# How to changed Json format?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I want to change format of displaying  Json.

I tried to printg whole Item object and it's printing all attributes(looks normal). I tried to change controller and service to return String and I tried to manipulate String but it is not a good approach to the problem i think. Must be something better.

```
{  
   "requestedUrl":"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=java&maxResults=40",
   "items":[  
      {  
         "id":"-SYM4PW-YAgC",
         "volumeInfo":{  
            "title":"The Religion of Java",
            "authors":[  
               "Clifford Geertz"
            ],
            "industryIdentifiers":[  
               {  
                  "type":"ISBN_10",
                  "identifier":"0226285103"
               },
               {  
                  "type":"ISBN_13",
                  "identifier":"9780226285108"
               }
            ],
            "readingModes":{  
               "text":true,
               "image":true
            },
            "pageCount":392,
            "printType":"BOOK",
            "categories":[  
               "Religion"
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

BookController.java

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class BookController {

    private BookService service;

    public BookController(BookService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping("book/{isbn}")
    public Item getBook(@PathVariable String isbn) {
        return service.findBookByISBN(isbn);
    }

}
```

BookService.java

```
public class BookService {

    public BookService() throws IOException {
    }


    public Item findBookByISBN(String isbn) {
// listOfItems taking json file from json file and making List<Item> to itarate over 
        for (Item item : listOfItems) {
            if (item.getVolumeInfo().getIndustryIdentifiers().get(0).getIdentifier().equals(isbn)) {
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Of Cours I have POJO class...

For `findBookByISBN(9780226285108)` 
json answear is

```
{
            "title":"The Religion of Java",
            "authors":[  
               "Clifford Geertz"
            ],
            "industryIdentifiers":[  
               {  
                  "type":"ISBN_10",
                  "identifier":"0226285103"
               },
               {  
                  "type":"ISBN_13",
                  "identifier":"9780226285108"
               }
            ],
            "readingModes":{  
               "text":true,
               "image":true
            },
            "pageCount":392,
            "printType":"BOOK",
            "categories":[  
               "Religion"
            ]
}
```

But I want to make my json like this :

```
{  
   "title":"The Religion of Java",
   "printType":"BOOK",
   "pageCount":392,
   "authors":[  
      "Clifford Geertz"
   ],
   "categories":[  
      "Religion"
   ]
}
```

Comment: show your `Item` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Data Transfer Object(DTO) and send only required information in response.

```
 {  
   "title":"The Religion of Java", 
   "printType":"BOOK",
   "pageCount":392,
   "authors":[  
     "Clifford Geertz"
    ],
   "categories":[  
    "Religion"
    ]
 }
```

In this case you can write a DTO like

```
 class NameYouWant{
String title;
String printType;
Integer pageCount;
List<String> authors = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
//generate getters and setters of the above data members.
 }
```

now when you are sending response set the data in this dto like this:-
create the object

```
 public Item findBookByISBN(String isbn) {
    for (Item item : listOfItems) {
        if (item.getVolumeInfo().getIndustryIdentifiers().get(0).getIdentifier().equals(isbn)) {
           NameYouWant na = new NameYouWant();
           na.setTitle(item.getTitle());
           na.setPrintType(item.getPrintType());
           na.setPageCount(item.getPageCount());
           na.SetAuthors(item.getAuthors());
           na.SetCategories(item.getCategories());
            return na;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In this way you can send only required data in the forntend.

Answer (score 0):

create an interface with Getters of required fields and cast your original object to new Interface. When you serialize this object it will produce required result.
e.g.

```
class Body implements BriefBody {
        String content;
        String type;
        // ---Getters/Setters---
    }

interface BriefBody {
    String getContent();
}

BriefBody getBriefBody() {
    Body body = new Body();
    body.setContent("bodyContent");
    body.setType("bodyType");
    return body;
}
```

Result will have {"content":"bodyContent"}.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new POJO for your expected response and in your BookService class (don't directly return the item) set the property and return.

Alternatively, create a new Item Object and set only the required property and return, assuming you're using Jackson Api for features like @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) and @JsonPropertyOrder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use marshalling your Item class to JSON in certain format. That will give u precisely what you want.  You will find out ways to do it in Spring Boot on google.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna create an additional DTO class or have many different views- you can use Jackson @JsonView annotation on class fields. Example :

1)create class :

```
public class View {
    public static class UI {}
    public static class NotUI {}
    public static class Rest {}
}
```

// you can create many different Views here;

2) annotate needed fields of your entity;

```
    class Book{   
    String title;    
    String printType;
@JsonView(View.Rest.class) 
    Integer pageCount;
```

// pageCount have 'Rest' view and when controller have 'UI' view - pageCount will be missing

3)Annotate the controller method with appropriate context:

```
@JsonView(View.UI.class)
  @GetMapping("book/{isbn}")
    public Item getBook(@PathVariable String isbn) {
        return service.findBookByISBN(isbn);
    }
```